# read/write to health kit didn't convert to Xcode 7: how to fix 'type of expression is ambiguous without more context' error?

Tags: healthkit, xcode7.3

when I converted from Xcode 6 to Xcode 7, reading and writing to HK store brought up the error "type of expression is ambiguous without more context" on the lines: 'let healthKitTypesToRead = Set(arrayLiteral:[' and 'let healthKitTypesToWrite = Set(arrayLiteral:["

```
// 1. Set the types you want to read from HK Store
let healthKitTypesToRead = Set(arrayLiteral:[
  HKObjectType.quantityTypeForIdentifier(HKQuantityTypeIdentifierHeartRate),
  HKObjectType.quantityTypeForIdentifier(HKQuantityTypeIdentifierActiveEnergyBurned),

  ])

// 2. Set the types you want to write to HK Store
let healthKitTypesToWrite = Set(arrayLiteral:[
   HKObjectType.quantityTypeForIdentifier(HKQuantityTypeIdentifierActiveEnergyBurned),
  ])
```

How can I fix this red alert error, or write alternative code to read/write to HK store?

Answer (score 0):

I just worked it out.'QuantityTypeForIdentifier' needed to be changed to characteristicTypeForIdentifier, and some other formatting changes:

```
  {
// 1. Set the types you want to read from HK Store
let healthKitTypesToRead = Set(arrayLiteral:
  HKObjectType.characteristicTypeForIdentifier(HKQuantityTypeIdentifierHeartRate)!,
  HKObjectType.characteristicTypeForIdentifier(HKQuantityTypeIdentifierActiveEnergyBurned)!
)

// 2. Set the types you want to write to HK Store
let healthKitTypesToWrite = Set(arrayLiteral:
  HKObjectType.characteristicTypeForIdentifier(HKQuantityTypeIdentifierActiveEnergyBurned)!
  )
```